# Recursion in async/await not resolve in main function

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to work with recursion in asynс/await functions. The problem is that I cannot get the final promise in the main function, in which I initially call the recursive method

```
async function delay(ms) {
  return await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function recursion(i) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (i == 0) {
      console.log(`i == 0`)
      resolve(i)
    } else {
      console.log(`i = ${i}. Wait 1 second...`)
      i--

      await delay(2000)
      await recursion(i)
    }
  })
}

async function main() {
  let i = await recursion(3)
  console.log(`END OF RECURSION`) //This code never use!
  console.log(`i => ${i}`)
}
main()
```

console.log:

```
i = 3. Wait 1 second...
i = 2. Wait 1 second...
i = 1. Wait 1 second...
i == 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is promise construction antipattern. There's already existing promise to chain, no need to create a new one. A promise that is returned from `Promise` callback is ignored, this breaks promise chain. Also, there is an inconsistency, the value isn't always returned from `recursion`.

It should be:

```
async function recursion(i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      console.log(`i == 0`)
      return i
    } else {
      console.log(`i = ${i}. Wait 1 second...`)
      i--

      await delay(2000)
      return recursion(i)
    }
}
```